# How to list recent posts in a wp nav menu?

Tags: posts, categories, menus

I've been trying this for some time and didn't get no clear answer.

I need to display 11 recent posts inside one of my menu items. My menu is like:

> ITEM 1 · MAMBA · ITEM 3

I need to display post titles and respective url's when rollover MAMBA. I got this code from [Joeyjoejoe's Category menu item and its last 10 posts as sub-menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56250/category-menu-item-and-its-last-10-posts-as-sub-menu/103197?noredirect=1#comment142515_103197) but pasted as is I can get recent posts for all submenu items as categories.

I had to change it a bit to appear only in MAMBA:

```
$category_ten_last_posts = array(
    'showposts' => 11,
    'category_name' => 'mamba',
```

and the target item:

```
$post->menu_item_parent = 45;
```

saddly the code started to repeat the recent posts list, in a duplicated maner:

Mamba

..........

Post 16

Post 15

...

Post 16

Post 15

...

My question here is how to list a controlled number of recent posts from a choosen category to a specific Menu Item?

Thank you for all the help you can give.

Best regards.
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about checking the ID value of each menu item like the following:

```
   if( $item->ID === 45):  // ADD THIS MENU-ITEM ID CHECK
        // Query the lasts ten category posts
        $category_ten_last_posts = array(
             'posts_per_page' => 11,
             'category_name' => 'mamba',
             'orderby' => 'date',
             'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts );
        foreach ( $posts  as $post ) {
            //...
         }
    endif;
```

ps: I moved the `get_posts()` out of the foreach input argument.

### Update

This works on my install:

```
!is_admin() AND add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item', 10, 3 );

// Add the ten last posts of af categroy menu item in a sub menu
function display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ){
    $menu_order = count($items); 
    $child_items = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ):
        if( $item->ID === 45 ): 
            // Query the lasts ten category posts
            $category_ten_last_posts = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 11,
                'category_name'  => 'mamba',
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                'order'          => 'DESC'
            );
            $posts = get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts );
            foreach( $posts as $post ):
                // Add sub menu item
                $post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
                $post->post_type        = 'nav_menu_item';
                $post->object           = 'custom';
                $post->type             = 'custom';
                $post->menu_order       = ++ $menu_order;
                $post->title            = $post->post_title;
                $post->url              = get_permalink( $post->ID );
                /* add children */
                $child_items[]          = $post;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}
```

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work :S
I've inserted this: `if( $item->ID === 45):  // ADD THIS MENU-ITEM ID CHECK`right above the "query the lasts" and changeded the foreach as you said... keeps the same dup!

Comment: It worked finally. I'm going to post the final result in the next 3 hours. Thank you birgire

Comment: ok great, I just posted my working solution ;-)

Comment: well your working solution as a mistake :D if( $item->ID === 45): it should end with a ; not with : can you correct it? And it's not the same script as mine! I'll post it later anyway ;)

Comment: I modified your script slightly ;-) (the `:` is actually not an error, it's part of the `if` sentence that ends with `endif`)

Comment: ok I got it! ;)