# Latest post in a specific menu

Tags: php, code

is it possible to show the latest posts only in a specific menu?

This is my menu:

```
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary' => __('Primary Navigation', 'gonzo'),
'mobile' => __('Mobile Navigation', 'gonzo'),
'copyright' => __('Footer Copyright Menu', 'gonzo'),
'toplevel' => __('Top Secondary Menu', 'gonzo')
 ));
```

[modifying this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56250/category-menu-item-and-its-last-10-posts-as-sub-menu/)

I want to show it only in "primary" menu. 
Thanks ;)

Comment: Do you mean the default listing of posts which you see on the home page?

Comment: Hi,
I need to show the latest post of a specific category in a specific menu.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood this correctly. You can add a menu item to any of the menu you like and select a category from the categories list on the left for that specific menu item. After saving the menu, you can check on the site and that menu link will show the latest posts for that specific category.

Comment: i have a category (id = 46) when i write posts on this category i would like to show the last 5 posts  into the menu of header (i have 4 menus and i want to show those only in the "primary" menu). Look at [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56250/category-menu-item-and-its-last-10-posts-as-sub-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

```
function latest_posts_menu($items, $args) {
//To a Specific Menu
if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {

    // Parent Menu Item
    $items .= '<li id="menu-item" class="menu-item">
                <a href="#">' . __('Latest Posts', 'textdomain') . '</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">';
    // Create Sub Menus
    foreach ( get_posts(
                array(
                    'posts_per_page'=>10,
                    'post_type' => array('post')
                    ) 
            ) as $post ) {
            // Menu Thumbnail. You can change the dimenssion as well as the image class
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(24,24), array("class" => "menu-thumb") );
        $items .= '<li class="sub-menu-item">
                        '.$thumb.'
                        <a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'. $post->post_title .'</a>
                    </li>';
    }
    // Close The Menu
    $items .= '</ul></li>';
}
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'latest_posts_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Source: [Display Latest Posts In Menu Item](http://www.itsabhik.com/display-latest-posts-in-menu-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks, can I also show the related thumbinal?

Comment: This code is good but it is not working fine with UberMenu because it not show the thumbnail and it needs to modified the classes manually.

Comment: Of course you can show related thumbnail. Just add the thumbnail as featured image. Code corrected to display the featured image before submenu.

Comment: Hi,Thanks but I have a trouble with the resize image, it show always the thumbnail 150x150 and not 24x24.

Comment: Put this on functions.php `add_image_size('menuthumbs' 24, 24, true);`. Then replace the dimension array (`array(24,24)`)with the thumbnail ID (i.e 'menuthumbs') in `get_the_post_thumbnail` function. All you need to do after that is rebuild the thumbnail using a plugin.